# Bash grep and storing its results

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep for a user given queue in all `*.idf.txt` files under a directory full of subdirectories that include the `*.idf.txt` files, and store the results so I can later enter those subdirectories.

The `grep` command I have is below and it works:

```
cmd = "grep -Rl --include=*.idf.txt " + queue + "/home/labani1/mkann_common/Projects/Expression_Atlas/data"
os.system(cmd)
```

But how do I do this in a way in which I can save the results to a list or another variable?

Comment: This seems to be more about *python* and grep than bash and grep - see for example [python + how to print value that comes from os.system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418616/python-how-to-print-value-that-comes-from-os-system)

Comment: Please clarify if you want an answer for Bash script or Python script

Answer (score 1):

You can use command substitution syntax with $(). So, for example,

```
VAR=`command-name`
VAR="`grep word /path/to/file`"
## or ##

VAR=$(command-name)
VAR="$(grep word /path/to/file)"
```

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-assign-a-grep-command-value-to-a-variable-in-linuxunix/